# Lync (2013) Client SDK does not work with Skype for Business Online

Tags: c#, powershell, lync-2013, skype-for-business

I have not been able to use S4B online with Lync 2013 client SDK yet. Throws exception while sharing the videos.
I tried it multiple ways in both UI Suppressed or Non-UI Suppressed but no luck. Had anyone been successful to have a working solution yet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

to have video using SDK you have to have enabled Open-gl,